# Messages from WordCOuntTopology are getting failed

Tags: java, centos, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I have two storm clusters - one is using Ubuntu. This cluster works fine, didn't have problems for a long time. And I just setted up a second cluster (with separate zookeeper, nimbus and supervisors) all on a separate machines. I added those lines to spout:

```
String msgid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
_collector.emit(new Values(sentence), msgid);
```

To check if messages are getting acknowledged. Also bolt has an ack method.

When I launch this topology on Ubuntu cluster - everything works fine. I can see messages are getting acknowledged by the spout.

But when I launch the same topology on CentOS cluster - messages are not getting acknowledged by the spout.

But there is no errors on Nimbus, Supervisor, Zookeeper.

Here is `zoo.cfg`

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
clientPort=2181

autopurge.purgeInterval=24
autopurge.snapRetainCount=5
```

Here is `storm.yaml`:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
    - "xxxxxxxxxxx"

nimbus.host: "xxxxxxxx"
nimbus.childopts: "-Xmx1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

ui.childopts: "-Xmx768m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

supervisor.childopts: "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
worker.childopts: "-Xmx768m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

storm.local.dir: "/mnt/storm"
```

I disabled Iptables, SElinux, Opened all ports in Security Groups (I'm on AWS)

Have no idea where to look for the problem.

P.S. currently I'm using 0.8.2 version of storm. But I also tried with 0.9.0.1. Tried both communication methods (ZeroMQ and Netty)

Comment: what are you seeing on the nimbus UI?

Comment: I saw that messages where picked up by spout, they where sent to the bolts, and where acked by bolts, but they nevier returned back to the spout. I mean spout never acked them , they just timed out and failed.